Why is my math formula to find the number of combinations on any rubiks cube not working in python?
N is the number of layers on the cube.
The formula works if N is 2 or 3.
import math
N = int(input("The number of layers on the cube:\n"))

def factorial(n):
  return math.factorial(n)
#Math
pt1 = factorial(7)*3**6*(24*2**10*factorial(12))**(N%2)*(factorial(24))**math.floor((N-2)/2)*(factorial(24)/factorial(4)**6)**math.floor(((N-2)/2)**2)
#Output

Ans=(int(pt1))
print(f'{Ans:,}')

Source of the formula
Test the formula and compare outputs
My code and output
I tried chatgpt.
I tried changing the math functions like factorials ect.
i tried splitting the equation into sections.
I need it to calculate it the way its supposed to.

Please don't post images of code/data/errors. You can edit your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: How to ask a good question

Did you separate the formula into parts and compare evaluations of the parts between Wolfram Alpha and Python?

The problem is in factorial(24)/factorial(4)**6: you use float division, so your pt1 is a float (you would have seen it if you hadn't converted immediatly to an int before printing), so it has limited precision and your int is only an approximation. Using factorial(24)//factorial(4)**6) (note the // for integer division) gives you an integer with full precision - and the correct, expected value.

There's no reason to wrap math.factorial in another function. Either call math.factorial directly, or use from math import factorial to get the function under the name you want.

math.factorial() works with floating point numbers. These have about 15 significance digits, which isn't enough to represent factorial(24) exactly.  If you'd brew your own factorial functions, purely working with Python integers, you'd get exact results. (You'd also need to replace math.floor((N-2)/2) by (N-2) // 2).

/ in Python does floating-point division, which is approximate with about 53 bits of precision. You want integer division instead, which is exact. Specifically, change the / here to //:
factorial(24)/factorial(4)**6
             ^ here

Contrary to a different answer, the / in things like math.floor((N-2)/2) doesn't actually matter: because N is a very small integer. (N-2)/2 is computed exactly in floating-point, and math.floor() converts it to an integer.
Good hint: so long as you need the int() call in the iine:

Ans=(int(pt1))

you're getting problems due to mistakenly using floating-point in a formula that requires exact integer arithmetic.
